# Can not download sources with Intellij Idea community 12.1.4 and maven 3.0.5

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I click "download sources and documentation" in Intellij Idea Community Edition 12.1.4 and get error that sources can not be downloaded.
But when I try:

```
mvn dependency:sources
```

All sources are downloaded.

What is the problem?

**P.S.** I have checked that Idea use the same maven that use in console. There are not any "off line" mode buttons triggered in Idea.

Comment: Try to get more information from your IDE. The error "sources can not be downloaded" isn't helpful.

Comment: It might be worth looking what .IntelliJIdea12\system\log\idea.log says when you attempt to download a source.  Do you need to setup a proxy in IntelliJ so that it can download sources from external maven repository ?

Comment: @AshutoshJindal good call, sounds like a proxy issue.

Comment: .IdeaIC12\system\log\idea.log does not contains any error or log information about error. I checked it after get an error and no thing changes. What do you mean by proxy issue? dependency:sources work correct but I did not configure any proxy with maven. Where I can see maven configuration about that and where I must put/copy analog configuration parameters to intellij idea?

Comment: Please mark ingara's answer as correct. Confirmed with IDEA 13.1.3

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Running `IDEA version 12.1.6` and I have the same issue.

When I uncheck the following option it does work:

`Settings > Maven > Importing > Use Maven3 to import project`

Comment: Solved it for IDEA version 13 as well.

Comment: Confirmed, works on IDEA 14. Thank you, @ingara, that would have taken a long time to find.

Comment: @EugeneEvdokimov  Where is this setting for IJ14? the settings completely changed.

Comment: search for "maven3" in settings and you will find it.

Comment: At least in IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.2, this option seems to be gone.

Comment: In 1.4.3, I had my settings to use my own install of Maven (3.2.3) and this would not work.  By switching to the bundled version of Maven 3, it started working.

Comment: Hello "me" from 2015!  It's 5 years later and I still have the same problem with the newest version of IntelliJ.  Why am I still using it?

Answer (score 64):

In **Intellij 2017.x, 2016.x, 15.x, 14.x** the given solution does not work as the option is removed.

The problem can be solved by changing `JDK for Importer` to a latest JDK instead of `User Internal JRE` which was 1.6.0 by default on Mac

The setting `JDK For Importer` can be found in:

> Preferences -> Build, Execution,Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven -> Importing

Comment: Worked on Intellij 15 EAP as well.

Comment: It worked! All is right with the world again. Thanks!

Comment: Because I'm behind a proxy, this worked for me due to certificates I had added to the `keystore`/`truststore` of my manually installed JDK/JRE.

Comment: I had to switch to my own Maven home directory instead of using the bundled one and click on "Re-import" for it to work

Answer (score 16):

I had the same issue with IntelliJ **IDEA 2016.1.3** and **Maven 3.2.1**. No solution mentioned here was working.
In my case a newer Maven version fixed the issue. With **Maven 3.3.9** IDEA can now download the sources.

Comment: I am using IntelliJ IDEA community version 2016.2 and also maven 3.3.9, but it is still not always working. When I hit "Download Source", status bar shows "Downloading maven sources", but after download is completed, it doesn't jump to the source code. I hit "Download Source" once again but remains the same. I have to restart IDEA to make it work.

Comment: Fixed it for me, I changed the bundled maven which was at version 3.0.5 to version 3.3.9 and it worked.

Comment: Worked for me as well after I switched to the version that is maintained by brew, which is 3.3.9 as of today. I had to restart IDE to make sure it works

Comment: In my case I had to change "Maven Home Directory" in IDEA settings. It was pointing to the old version that didn't exist.

Answer (score 6):

"I had the same issue with IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.3 and Maven 3.2.1. No solution mentioned here was working. In my case a newer Maven version fixed the issue. With Maven 3.3.9 IDEA can now download the sources."

anything's already in the former answers...

- download sources in your repo

  `mvn dependency:sources`
- F4 on the class you want to check the sources out
- locate the source jar in your local repository

maybe it is not a full IDE solution, but hope it solves your issue

Comment: In some reason clicking on "Download Sources" in IntelliJ didn't open the sources for me automatically, so clicking on "F4" opened the sources, thanks. But it's weird that previously I didn't need to press F4...

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issue with IntelliJ 2016.2.4.  As user526177 posted udating the Maven version fixes it but for my needs switching to the bundled Maven 2 was just fine and fixed the issue.

[Screenshot (can't embed yet due to rank)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7Mhg.png)

Comment: Switching to Maven2 (bundled) was the only thing that worked for me... with latest Maven installed (Maven 3.3.9) and IntelliJ Ultimate 2016.3.2.

Answer (score 3):

I use IDEA 2017.1.3, I just change the Maven home directory option(Preferences -> Build, Execution,Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven -> Maven home directory) of default Maven 3 to Maven 2, I believe it's the same solution for newer version of IDEA just like the selected answer. And it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue, and sources weren't being downloaded since I needed credentials from my project's *specific* `settings.xml`.

To fix (Intellij 2018.1.2):

File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Maven

and provide the appropriate `settings.xml` in the 'User settings file' section

Comment: A custom settings.xml was my problem too.  Once I removed it (temporarily), intellij was able to download source documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this by use jdk 1.8  in MAVEN -> RUNNER -> JRE .my idea version is 2016.2

Answer (score 0):

I changed the java version in pom.xml to match my jdk's version and it worked for me.

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

     <!--earlier this was 1.8-->
    <java.version>10</java.version>

</properties>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's necessary to check availability of repositories.

For example, if you use corporate repository but **don't use** VPN just right now. In this case maven can't download sources (of open-source project) if one of your repositories isn't accessible.

You can comment specific `<repository>` in your `pom.xml` file.