# Intellij idea - can't make Maven work

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I just last version of instaill Intellij idea on the new computer and can't make Maven work properly with empty project.

When it starts Maven try to download all it's plugins, but it stuck in infinite download. I try to add some dependcy and get infinity download of that dependcy

[image: First]

I have found a lot of peoples with such [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18779183/can-not-download-sources-with-intellij-idea-community-12-1-4-and-maven-3-0-5) [like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727356/intellij-idea-cannot-resolve-anything-in-maven) this and a lot of others, but this solution doesn't work for me.

I already install last version of Maven instead of Maven inserted in idea:
[image: Second]

Also I try to update information from main repository manual in idea Maven settings and got such error:

> transfer for nexus-maven-repository-index.properties failed

There is [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22593733/intellij-idea-13-1-updating-maven-repository-index-authentication-failure) with problem like this, but it doesn't work for me either.
And if I try to use Maven from Terminal like this:

> mvn -U idea:idea

(also I try to add proxy settings as arguments here) I've got such problems:

> Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5: Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
>   for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5

And a lot of problems like this with other plugins.

Try to use proxy in settings.xml and as commands in idea settings of Maven:
[image: Third]
As @Tunaki already said add of proxy helped in most of cases, but not mine.
My settings.xml:
[image: proxy]

Comment: This is usually a proxy problem. Are you behind one?

Comment: @Tunaki, year see at the last screen.
Also I try to use proxy with settings.xml(without restarting of computer - but I think it doesn't matter)